# Theme or coloring issue in android

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm stuck in a unknown issue of coloring. I develop an food delivery application. I set the design of application, for example i take Food Menu screen. Actual output of screen :

[image]

I run the app on almost 6 mobiles include samsung, q-mobile, huawei. It works perfect.
But when i run the app on another random  samsung mobile it show me the layout like this:

[image]

I don't know why this dark gray appear in boxes bakcground. This is happening in only one mobile of samsung. I'm confused because i also check on samsung on other mobile with same android version and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same thing was happening to me on my OnePlus phone. The solution I use was that I added background color for all component that was not using correct color on my OP phone. So in the case of CardView's that you have below, I added `app:cardBackgroundColor` property to CardView XML component view and it started to show just fine. I didn't investigate any further to know what was the reason behind this, but as you said, it almost certainly got to do something with a different Theme on that Samsung.

Comment: I will try your solution, Thank you for your response. I face this problem on textView also on other screen. I give black to textview and it show white. The confusion is not all the textview change color. Some change and some not change